# Form element not getting submitted while echoing it from PHP

Tags: php, html, forms, submit

While echoing a form from PHP with some predefined value retrieved from file from php i have come across a trouble.

i can see those predefined values in both input boxes as expected that is Content and Title of the article.

But whenever i click on the submit the Content part of form is not getting submitted.

when i do print_r($_REQUEST); i only see following o/p
Array ( [action] => edit_art [art_id] =>11 $art_id [title] => TCS [agree] => on )

when i don't provide predefined value for Content input box (textarea) it is getting submitted with whatever i type in it.

my code is as follows

```
echo '<form  action="art_action.php?action=edit_art&art_id=$art_id" method="post"><br />
<p><b>Article Title</b></p>
<input type="text" name="title" **value='.$art_title.'**/><br />
<span id="title_check"></span><br />
<p><b>Content</b></p><br />
<textarea cols="75" rows="20"  **value='.$content.'**  name="content"></textarea><br />
<span id="content_check"></span>
<div class="content" ><input type="checkbox" name="agree" style="margin-right:10px"/>Agree Terms and Conditions first.<span id="agree_check"></span><br />
<input type="button" onclick="varify_and_post_article(this.form)" Value="Post Article"/><br />
</form>';
```

Please help me out.
Thanx in advance !!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A textarea has no `value` attribute, you should put the `$content` inside the tags

```
echo '<textarea cols="75" rows="20" name="content">'.$content.'</textarea>'
```

Answer (score 0):

You may encode variables inside brackets.

ie:

> `echo "<input value={$variable} />"`

or more well-formed

```
echo "<input value='{$variable}' />"
```